# what's the meaning of "if not"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "if not"

For example:

> One has his father-in-law as well as his daughter-in-law living with him, or his own child **if not** his step-son or step-father.

[(source)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Wbg1AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=%22or%20his%20own%20child%20if%20not%20his%20stepson%22&source=bl&ots=QCP-dV8Um0&sig=kUYQdA9ZE5MvgYfvtSqibkXRx34&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V0N5U8n_NMHnPMLEgOAL&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22or%20his%20own%20child%20if%20not%20his%20stepson%22&f=false)

Comment: It's a pretty strange sentence, so without additional context it's not easy to say whether **if not** "validly" means **although not** (or perhaps **even though not necessarily**), or if all it means is the original author doesn't speak/write English very well. Or maybe something else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not sure I agree with you on this one.  I see "if not" here in the same sense as "Let's get together tomorrow if not sooner."

Comment: @user6413 I couldn't make sense of your sentence, unless that comma were deleted. If I can ignore that comma, I can read the sentence like this: *One has his [father-in-law as well as his daughter-in-law] living with [him or his own child] if not (with) [his step-son or step-father].* But I'm not sure if your text is really supposed to be written that way (without the comma). It'd be the best for everyone if you could clarify it.

Comment: @BobRodes: Maybe that's another possible reading. Like I said, the sentence is weird anyway. I've just gone to the trouble of [finding the context](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Wbg1AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=%22or+his+own+child+if+not+his+stepson%22&source=bl&ots=QCP-dV8Um0&sig=kUYQdA9ZE5MvgYfvtSqibkXRx34&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V0N5U8n_NMHnPMLEgOAL&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22or%20his%20own%20child%20if%20not%20his%20stepson%22&f=false). It seems to be *the actual words* from [Fulcher of Chartres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulcher_of_Chartres) (1059-11??).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the meaning of a text which seems to date from C12 or earlier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not possible—Modern English didn't exist back then, so these words certainly couldn't date from the 12th century.  Rather, this is a Modern English translation of what Fulcher of Chartres wrote in Latin.  Compare the same passage in [an alternative translation](http://www.fordham.edu/halsall/source/fulcher-cde.asp): "Some have with them father-in-law, or daughter-in-law, or son-in-law, or stepson, or step-father."

Comment: @snailplane: Fair enough. But I stand by my closevote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers strange to see your closevoting every time stating it's *old* or *archaic*. Isn't it English after all? How do we avoid coming across it! :)

Comment: @Maulik: There are lots of archaic forms that even native speakers don't recognise. Although as snailplane points out, OP's text is actually a modern translation, s/he also provides a link to an alternative version where the questionable ***if not*** is simply rendered as ***or*** the same as all the others. Unless you're a social anthropologist specialising in C12 "Byzantine" attitudes towards the cultural intermingling of Franks, Jews, Muslims, and Christians, it's difficult to know the full context and thus understand the *exact* likely meaning of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "one" at the beginning suggests that this is a set of examples of a type.  "One might have his father-in-law..." would substitute in the sentence without changing the meaning, although the flavor would be a little less emphatic.  So, in this sentence, "if not" has the basic meaning of "or perhaps" or "or even".

The writer appears to be talking about a culture or group in which extended family live together.  For example, the sentence might begin "In the neighborhoods on the south side of the city, one has..."

[Here's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/if+not) a definition of "if not".

Comment: Having actually *read* the context, I think your interpretation is probably correct. But it seems to be *very* old text, so one must be careful of assuming anything based on either current use of English, or conventional modes of thought in a social philosophy context. Basically, the question as it stands is pretty pointless unless you're going to go to the trouble of explaining how (and why) *in other superficially similar contexts,* "if not" can just as easily mean "**although not**", rather than "**or even**".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around "if not" meaning "although not".  Can you provide an example?

Comment: That's a good question, if not a great one. How can I convince you that what I mean there is *"Although that's not actually a **great** question, nevertheless it is a **good** question"*. I'm sure in the spoken form it would be obvious from intonation. How about if I wrote it as... "That's a *good* question, if not a great one."?

Comment: Oh, there it is.  "That's a good *question*, if *not* a GREAT one" has my meaning.  "That's a GOOD question, if not a *great* one" has yours.  I must have been getting sleepy.  Funny the dictionaries don't seem to have that interpretation listed.

Comment: It might be a bit more tricky than simply playing with available orthographic features for stressing single words. I'm not actually sure exactly what different emphasis is implied by capitals as opposed to italics, and I'm not even 100% certain that the distinction can be *completely and unambiguously* made by intonation alone. But at least you accept that there are at least two very different meanings.

Comment: Yes, it might be a bit more tricky.  If you don't mind, we'll call my attempt a rough approximation of perhaps one way of conveying the different meanings.  I was using caps to mean primary emphasis, and italics to mean secondary emphasis.  I don't know why I was drawing a blank on your meaning, but thanks for going to the trouble of reminding me of it.

Comment: I wonder if this question hasn't "poisoned the well" for a potentially interesting question about the two different meanings of *if not* in such constructions. Personally I have no idea what the prevailing attitudes towards sharing dwellings with stepsons and stepfathers were in C12 Jerusalem (and whether fathers/daughters-in-law were seen as much the same, or radically different). One (or two, *contrasting*) modern example usages in contexts that reflect more familiar concepts would have been *so* much better.

Comment: I guess I didn't think of the other possible meaning because the idea of having a stepchild or stepparent living in one's house is a step further from any norm that I can think of from the idea of one's own child doing so.  But as you say, you never know.

Comment: That "you never know" precisely encapsulates my primary reason for closevoting. I imagine hardly any currently-living Anglophones have any idea what if any distinction C12 Franks made between "step-" relatives and "in-laws" in the context of shared domiciles. So deciding between different interpretations of OP's cited usage is more a matter of (ancient) social anthropology than (current) English usage.

Comment: Personally, I'd say we have a pretty good idea what distinction would be drawn, given an average knowledge of European history.  But I'm an optimist.  :)